# How to render a list from a JSON url? - ReactJS hooks

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, list, fetch

I want to render a list from a [JSON URL](https://jsonkeeper.com/b/Z51B). However, I have the following error: **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: Failed to fetch). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.** What am I going wrong? Thanks for your answer

```js
//hooks.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useFetch = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {

    setLoading(true)
    setError(null)

    fetch('https://jsonkeeper.com/b/Z51B')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        setLoading(false)
        if (json.data) {
          setData(json.data)
        } else {
          setData([])
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])
  return { data, loading, error }
}
```

```js
//index.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { useFetch } from "./hooks.js";
import {CardItem} from './card';

export const List = () => {
    
    const { data, loading, error } = useFetch()

    if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
    if (error) return <div>{error}</div>

    return (
      <>
            <ul>
                {data.map((item: any, index: any) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        {item.names.map((name: any) => {
                            return <CardItem
                                family={item.family}
                                name={name}
                        />
                        })
                        }
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
      </>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Please check the variables `data`, `item.names` that you run `map()`. Maybe you expect array but they are objects

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with your `setError(err)` in `catch` block of your custom hook. It should be `setError(err.message)`.